# MongoDB partial index doesn't work with $elemMatch

Tags: mongodb

I have following document:

```
user{
  _id: objId(..),
  name: "John Doe",
  transactions:[
    {
      _id: 1,
      amount: 10.00
      item_id: 123,
      condition: SUCCESS 
    },
    {
      _id: 2,
      amount: 5.00
      item_id: 124,
      condition: FAILED
    }
    ..
  ]
  ..
}
```

I tried placing a partial index for failed transactions using:

```
db.user.createIndex(
   { "transactions.condition": 1 },
   { partialFilterExpression: {"transactions.condition": "FAILED"} }
)
```

But whenever I do a query or $match through aggregate pipeline with followiing:

```
{$match: {"transactions": {$elemMatch: {"condition": "FAILED"}}}}
```

I always get a full document scan `COLLSCAN` with `explain()`. I am guessing the filter needs to strictly  to follow expression of `transactions.condition: "FAILED"`, but I thought `{"transactions": {$elemMatch: {"condition": "FAILED"}}}` was identicial to `transactions.condition: "FAILED"` if you just do one expression. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, try this instead:

```
db.user.explain().aggregate({$match: {"transactions.condition": "FAILED"}})
```

The reason is that MongoDB doesn't build the index for you. It has to be a `key`.

---

You'll get a even faster query if you can reduce it to:

```
db.user.explain().aggregate([
{$match: {"transactions.condition": "FAILED"}},
{$project:{_id:0, transactions.condition:1}}
])
```

but that may not be the case here.

Comment: Gotcha. but what if I want to index something like `{"transactions": {$elemMatch: {"condition": "FAILED", "amount": {$gt: 10}}}}}`. Is this possible with partial index?

Comment: I don't think so, and this is why: if you create an index on `transactions.condition`, mongodb uses that index collection and gets the `_id`s. Next it says, "ok, filter amount > 10 on this subset". That's fine. But you're asking also: "I need you to remember the index of the item in the array"; so that seems to me not possible. @夢のの夢. You can try $map, or $filter; I did it locally but that requires collscan. Indexes in array of subdocuments are problematic.

Comment: but tbh, your question was already answered. @夢のの夢

Comment: not sure about the remembering index part, thought mongo would index document if its array field contains any element satisfies `elemMatch`. but yeah I will ask in a separate post. thanks.